# ASP.NET COR 2 handler to handle HTTP 4xx errors for WEB API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Similar to UseExceptionHandler which handles the HTTP 5xx errors, is there any handler provided by ASP.NET CORE 2 to handle the HTTP 4xx errors.

Here I am trying to catch any HTTP 4xx errors produced during the request processing pipeline and process it with send it back to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new middleware to handle your exceptions:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">Next request in the pipeline</param>
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into middleware logic
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Current http context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Error = "Internal Server error" });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Use it like this in your `Startup.cs`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am already using the UseExceptionHandler to catch the HTTP 5xx errors. I tried to debug and see if it handle the 4xx errors but found it is not catching those errors.

Comment: `By default, an app doesn't provide a rich status code page for HTTP status codes, such as 404 Not Found. To provide status code pages, use Status Code Pages Middleware.` According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1 I think you should be using StatusCodePages. But in WEB API you shouldn't return HTML. You should return some type of serializable data which is what my middleware does by returning JSON. Look at their example, they return a plain text result.

Comment: I tried the code that you mentioned but I see any HTTP 4xx errors are not getting trapped by the ErrorHandlingMiddleware

Comment: Yes, that's because 4xx is not an exception. If you controller action returns 4xx that means the controller action is handling the resulting value. This will only work for exception that you didn't handle in your code.

Comment: Thanks much for the details